# Word2vec raise KeyError(f"Key '{key}' not present")

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, word2vec

Currently using gensim 4.0 library to write the code. However, I don't know why it keeps failing in finding a similar word. At first, when I set up min_count = 5, the error is, that it wants me to build a vocab first, but after I reduce it to min_count = 1, it says, key error not present...Full code with datasets over here: https://github.com/JYjunyang/FYPDEMO Am I writing something wrong or missing some important steps? Everything works fine but just this word2vec implementation...Will appreciate for every guidance provided...
**Take note: LemmaColumn is a dataframe after lemmatization**

```
def FeaturesExtraction():
    word2vec = 
Word2Vec(sentences=LemmaColumn,vector_size=100,window=5,min_count=1,workers=8,sg=1)
    b1 = time.time()
    train_time = time.time() - b1
    print(word2vec.wv.most_similar('virus', topn=10))
```

And I not sure why, after training with 10k data, unique words in vocabulary only have 7:
word #0/7 is t
word #1/7 is l
word #2/7 is x
word #3/7 is e
word #4/7 is _
word #5/7 is u
word #6/7 is f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `LemmaColumn` variable probably isn't in the format `Word2Vec` needs for the `sentences` argument. It needs a Python sequence: something than can be iterated over multiple times, like a list, or another re-iterable object. And in that sequence, every individual item must itself be a list-of-string-tokens (words).

Your tiny vocabulary is instead what I'd expect to see if instead:

```
LemmaColumn = [ 
    ['f', 'u', 'l', 'l', '-', 't', 'e', 'x', 't'],
]
```

…or even…

```
LemmaColumn = [ 
    ['full-text'],
]
```

…because Python will happily treat a plain string (like `'full-text'`) as if it were a list filled with 1-character strings. Thus your entire training vocabular is only the characters of that single string – likely a column-name, rather than the column-data you want to be using.

Double-check what's in `LemmaColumn`. Perform the necessary transformations on the column's data to make it the kind of sequence `Word2Vec` expects, & confirm it looks sensible before trying `Word2Vec`.

Also: running with logging on to at least the `INFO` level will show a lot more of the model's progress, and as you learn to understand the reported steps/progress, things like weirdly-low counts of texts/words, or steps that'd take time if they were working on the right amount (lots) of data completing instantly, will be evident sooner.

Finally, note that `min_count=1` is essentially always a bad idea with an algorithm like word2vec. Good vectors only come from multiple varied examples of the same word's usage – hence the default `min_count=5`. Keeping rare words not only tends to get poor vectors for those rare words, but the fact that natural-language text tends to have lots of such rare words means so much of the model's time & space is devoted to the (nearly hopeless) task of improving those junk words' vectors that other nearby words' vectors suffer as well.

Comment: thanks for the help! I was able to solve it now! However, only 20 unique words are available for this model. May I ask is it my parameter problem causing these low unique words? Because the original dataset was 600k...
Parameter I used:
word2vec = Word2Vec(sentence,vector_size=300,window=5,workers=8,min_count=1,sg=1,negative=5,ns_exponent=5,max_vocab_size=None)

Comment: What are the 20 words? Have you examined the data you're passing in to make sure it's the right format? (That is: a re-iterable Python sequence where each item is a list-of-strings.) Also, `min_count=1` still a bad idea for real work (as opposed to quickie tests), and `ns_exponent=5` is a bizarre choice I've never seen before, so odd to see from someone still struggling to get basic stuff working. Where was that non-default value suggested as a good idea?